# Can I get sued for copying a 1973 Swedish film?

Tags: india, public-domain, sweden

I am a newbie novelist and in my novel, I have copied a small part from the 1973 Swedish film [Scenes from a Marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scenes_from_a_Marriage). I am from India and the film is Swedish. I want to ask, is the film in public domain after so many years? If I get published can I get sued for coping that part?

Comment: I changed the title b/c the film is fiction, not a documentary. It "draws on" the director's experiences, but does not report them directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under [Swedish copyright law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_law_of_Sweden), a work such as a movie is protected for 70 years after the death of the "creator". It is unclear who the copyright holder is, but it has not been 70 years since the film was made. Unless it was explicitly "released into the public domain", it is still protected, so you can get sued.